# A word to describe Moriarty's character in BBC's Sherlock

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that describe the following individual

"A person who commits crime but knows the law (how it works), always dodges the charges and because of this  never gets caught."
e.g. a man kills someone and everybody knows he did, but the police can't arrest him due to lack of evidence.
Or a hacker who hacks a machine and removes all logs and evidence so that he won't get caught for his crime.

Comment: I suppose you might call him a "clever crook", but the concept is not at all related to "white collar crime" (which is only one of several contexts where "white collar" is meaningful).

Comment: I think you should start by looking up 'white collar' and considering how much the fact of being engaged in non-manual work is pertinent. White collar crime leads to convictions all the time, murder isn't a white-collar crime. Reasons for lack of evidence are varied and can include luck, sophistication of crime planning and innocence.

Comment: @HotLicks white collar in our culture means as i described, i'd checked that, yes its not what i was meaning, i am looking for adjective to describe Moriarty character in BBC's Sherlock.

Comment: @Spagirl Ye, right. no white-collar. im exactly looking for a a word that describes a intelligent person who always do planned crimes and never get caught because of yhis.

Comment: "White collar crime" refers to crimes that consist of manipulating words and numbers, rather than violence  -- eg, embezzlement, or altering legal documents to one's advantage.  *Occasionally* the term will be applied to someone who non-violently steals physical objects from the company where they work, but even that is not the usual definition..

Comment: The usual term for describing Moriarty is "sinister".  (Though I suppose some consider that to be a right-handed complement.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **mastermind**

> 1.1 A person who plans and directs an ingenious and complex scheme or enterprise.
>   *‘McAvoy was the mastermind of the robbery’*

(Oxford)

But a mastermind can get caught, just as Moriarty eventually was.

To be more specific, a *criminal mastermind*, or *master criminal*.

Answer (score 0):

Nouns or adjectives for "A person who commits crime but knows the law and because of this never get caught" (or avoids justice), with connotations of "white collar" indicating that they don't shoot or murder their way out of justice, but rather finagle their way out or avoid it altogether.

**Well connected** Do Liberals mete out justice differently for well connected?
http://www.therebel.media/do_liberals_mete_out_justice_differently_for_well_connected

**Having friends in high places** s the saying goes, it's good to have friends in high places. That is, until a photo of the Chief Justice Joseph Bevilacqua's indiscretions landed...
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22friends+in+high+places%22+justice&tbm=nws&*

**slippery** or **slippery customer** 
"Someone who is slippery cannot be trusted" He's as slippery as an eel - you can never get a straight answer out of him.
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/slippery

**smooth criminal** Smooth Escaped From Prison & Convinced A Cop He Was Jogging!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czP0Q_dWqso

Comment: having friend in high places is  the closet one in the list, i'd checked them all,but none matched what i looking for, and i found my question is ambiguous, please check the edited version  too. thank you

Comment: Yes, I wish you'd mentioned in the first place you wanted a word to describe Moriarty